# Fraction.java Keep getting object address not the values I want

Tags: java, fractions

I am working on this program and keep getting this result.

To convert fractional measures,
 enter the fractional measure you want to convert: 3/4

Enter the fractional amount to reduce/increase it by: 1/2

The converted measurement is: **Fraction@6750cf54**

The part is bold is the problem.

This is my main program.

```
import java.util.*;  // Scanner
import java.io.*;    // PrintStream

public class Pierre1 extends Object 
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    PrintStream theScreen = new PrintStream(System.out);
    Scanner theKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    theScreen.println("\nTo convert fractional measures,");
    theScreen.print(" enter the fractional measure you want to convert: ");
    Fraction oldMeasure = new Fraction();
    oldMeasure.read(theKeyboard);



    theScreen.print("\nEnter the fractional amount to reduce/increase it by: ");
    Fraction scaleFactor = new Fraction(1,6);
    scaleFactor.read(theKeyboard);


    Fraction newMeasure = oldMeasure.times(scaleFactor);

    theScreen.print("\nThe converted measurement is: ");
    theScreen.print(newMeasure);
    theScreen.println();
    theScreen.println();

    }
}
```

This is my other program.

```
import java.util.*;  // Scanner
import java.io.*;    // PrintStream

public class Fraction extends Object
{
    private int myNumerator = 0;
    private int myDenominator = 0;
    public void print(PrintStream out)
    {
        System.out.print(myNumerator + "/" + myDenominator);
    }
    public Fraction()
    {
    myNumerator = 0;
    myDenominator = 1;
    }   

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
    myNumerator = numerator;
    myDenominator = denominator;
    }       
    private int numerator()
    {
    return myNumerator;
    }       

    private int denominator()
    {
    return myDenominator;
    }       

    public void read (Scanner in)
    {
    String fraction = in.next();
    StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(fraction, "/", false);
    if (parser.countTokens() != 2)
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad Fraction Format");
    myNumerator = Integer.parseInt(parser.nextToken());
    myDenominator = Integer.parseInt(parser.nextToken());
    }

    Fraction times(Fraction rightOperand)
    {
    Fraction result
        = new Fraction(myNumerator*rightOperand.numerator(), 
               myDenominator*rightOperand.denominator());

    result.simplify(result);
    return result;
    }


    public Fraction simplify(Fraction getGcd)
    {
        Fraction result = new Fraction();
        int num = numerator();
        int den = denominator();        
        int gcd = greatestCommonDivisor(num, den);
        if (gcd == 0)
            return result;
        else
        {
            myNumerator = myNumerator / gcd;
            myDenominator = myDenominator / gcd;
        }

        return result;
    }


private static int greatestCommonDivisor(int alpha, int beta)
{
    alpha = Math.abs(alpha);  // take absolute values of operands
    beta = Math.abs(beta);

    if (beta == 0)       // base case
        return alpha;
    else                 // induction step
    {
        int remainder = alpha % beta;

        return greatestCommonDivisor(beta, remainder);
    }
    }

}
```

What do I need to do to fix this?
I have been scanning the programs to find the problem, but my limited java experience is getting the best of me. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think it should print anything else? What does Java know about your custom class?

Comment: The key is `toString()`. Give your classes a decent toString override method, one that returns a String that well represents your class's state.

Comment: it is the hashCode of the object not its address, btw.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the Fraction class that I use (it fixes some of your flaws: numerator and denumerator should be final, etc.)

```
// code by jph
package sys.mat;    

/** non degenerate integer fraction in normal form */
public class Fraction implements Comparable<Fraction> {
  /** numerator */
  public final int num;
  /** denominator (always greater than zero) */
  public final int den;

  public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
      return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
  }

  /** @param num
   * @param den has to be non-zero
   * @throws {@link ArithmeticException} if den is zero */
  public Fraction(final int num, final int den) {
    int gcd = gcd(num, den);
    int res = den / gcd;
    if (0 < res) {
      this.num = num / gcd;
      this.den = res;
    } else {
      this.num = -num / gcd;
      this.den = -res;
    }
  }

  public Fraction add(Fraction myFraction) {
    return new Fraction(num * myFraction.den + den * myFraction.num, den * myFraction.den);
  }

  public Fraction sub(Fraction myFraction) {
    return new Fraction(num * myFraction.den - den * myFraction.num, den * myFraction.den);
  }

  public Fraction mul(Fraction myFraction) {
    return new Fraction(num * myFraction.num, den * myFraction.den);
  }

  public Fraction mul(int myInt) {
    return new Fraction(num * myInt, den);
  }

  public Fraction div(Fraction myFraction) {
    return new Fraction(num * myFraction.den, den * myFraction.num);
  }

  /** also denoted reciprocal
   * 
   * @return den/num */
  public Fraction inverse() {
    return new Fraction(den, num);
  }

  /** @return true if den == 1 */
  public boolean isInteger() {
    return den == 1;
  }    

  public double toDouble() {
    return num / (double) den;
  }

  /** may only be called if isInteger() returns true
   * 
   * @return num */
  public int toInteger() {
    if (!isInteger()) // assert den == 1
      throw new RuntimeException(toString() + " is no integer");
    return num;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Fraction myFraction) {
    // return num * myFraction.den - den * myFraction.num; // does not work for big integers
    return Double.compare(toDouble(), myFraction.toDouble());
  }

  public boolean equalsInteger(int value) {
    return equals(new Fraction(value, 1));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object myObject) {
    if (myObject == null) // || !(myObject instanceof Fraction)
      return false;
    Fraction myFraction = (Fraction) myObject;
    return num == myFraction.num && den == myFraction.den; // sufficient since in normal form
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    // n / 1 is mapped to n, thus is identical to getInteger()
    return num + den - 1;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return num + "/" + den;
  }      
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about toString. Thank you very much for the help